# Getting statistics from different groups of rows

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I've started using Pandas in Python to solve the following problem:

I have an excel file where I have the mass values of all bird species. So basically, there are two columns: 'Order Name' and 'Mass Value'. What I want to do is get statistics (with .describe() I guess) of the mass, for each order of birds, and store them somehow.

So far I've tried creating a dataframe with the different Orders as columns, and then trying to get all mass values for each, but then I get some issue with the fact that the indexes don't match. I'm fairly new with Python so I'm really open to any ideas :)

Thanks!

Tiago

Comment: can you share some more details(errors & code)

Comment: Can you add sample of data and desired output? The best is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
result = df.groupby('A')['B'].describe().unstack()
```

yields (something like)

```
   count      mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
A                                                      
0    5.0  6.800000  1.923538  4.0  6.00  7.0  8.00  9.0
1    3.0  5.333333  4.725816  0.0  3.50  7.0  8.00  9.0
4    3.0  2.666667  1.154701  2.0  2.00  2.0  3.00  4.0
5    2.0  3.000000  1.414214  2.0  2.50  3.0  3.50  4.0
6    1.0  4.000000       NaN  4.0  4.00  4.0  4.00  4.0
7    2.0  5.500000  2.121320  4.0  4.75  5.5  6.25  7.0
8    3.0  2.333333  2.081666  0.0  1.50  3.0  3.50  4.0
9    1.0  7.000000       NaN  7.0  7.00  7.0  7.00  7.0
```

So simply change `'A'` to `'Order Name'` and `B` to `'Mass Value'`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm sorry I didn't provide any more information. but that's exactly what I wanted anyway!